# it gives me expected identifier before { token

Tags: c++, if-statement, integer, operators

The problem is that I don't know what the problem is. I have tried to look it up, in my opinion everything seem right, but somehow it is not.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int s,a;
    cin >>a;
    if (a=!0)and(a<=1000000)
        {s=a*(a+1)/2;
        cout <<s;}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Missing `#include <iostream>`

Comment: @RichardCritten The missing include was there but not shown properly due to improper code formatting.

Answer (score 6):

In C++ the selection if statement is defined the following way

```
selection-statement: 
    if ( condition ) statement 
    if ( condition ) statement else statement
```

As it is seen the condition shall be enclosed in parentheses.

Also you have a typo in this sub-expression

```
if (a=!0)and(a<=1000000)
    ****
```

That is this expression

```
a=!0
```

is equivalent to

```
a = !0
```

and denotes an assignment of the expression `!0` to the variable `a` that is equivalent to

```
a = 1
```

So you have to write either

```
if ( ( a != 0 ) and ( a <= 1000000 ) )
```

or

```
if ( a != 0 and a <= 1000000 )
```

Also pay attention to that the variable `s` should be declared as having the type `long long int`.

```
long long int s;
int a;
```

Otherwise the expression in the right hand side of the assignment

```
    s = a*(a+1)/2;
```

can result in overflow.

So you should write for example

```
long long int s;
int a;

//…

s = ( long long int )a * ( a + 1 ) / 2;
```

Taking all what was said into account your program can look the following way.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int s;
    int a;

    cin  >> a;

    if ( a != 0 and a <= 1'000'000 )
    {
        s = ( long long int )a * ( a + 1 ) / 2;
        cout  << s  << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If for example to enter

```
1000000
```

then the program output will be

```
500000500000
```

Answer (score 1):

This: `if (a=!0)and(a<=1000000)` is missing a pair of parentheses (and you probably meant `a!=0` rather than `a=!0` which is something *quite* different). It should probably be `if ((a!=0)and(a<=1000000))`.

Comment: There's also `a = !0` which is probably meant to be `a != 0`.